# Horizontally sizing Bootstrap 3 media object body

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to equally size the .media-body elements so they can grow up to the left limit of the page no matter the text they wrap.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="media">
    <a class="media-left" href="#">
        <img class="media-object" data-src="holder.js/64x64">
    </a>
    <div class="media-body">
      <p class="text-justify deal-text" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur dipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero.</p>
   </div>
    <a class="media-right" href="#">
        <img class="media-object" data-src="holder.js/64x64">
    </a>
</div>
  <div class="media">
    <a class="media-left" href="#">
        <img class="media-object" data-src="holder.js/64x64">
    </a>
    <div class="media-body">
      <p class="text-justify deal-text" >Lorem ipsum</p>
   </div>
    <a class="media-right" href="#">
        <img class="media-object" data-src="holder.js/64x64">
    </a>
</div>
  <div class="media">
    <a class="media-left" href="#">
        <img class="media-object" data-src="holder.js/64x64">
    </a>
    <div class="media-body">
      <p class="text-justify deal-text" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero.</p>
   </div>
    <a class="media-right" href="#">
        <img class="media-object" data-src="holder.js/64x64">
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's the [snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/oxba1d0o/)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work...

```
<style>
  .media-body {
    width: 100% ;
  }
</style>
```